# Why c++ static member was not initialized in this case?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, cmake, static

`registerT` is not called and the function was not registered in the map. I have no clue. This is the code.

//factory.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cxxabi.h>
template <typename BaseType, typename... Args>
class Factory {
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<BaseType> Make(const std::string &name) {
        return constructMap().at(name)();
    }
public:
    template <typename T>
    class Registrar : public BaseType {
        public:
            friend T;
            static bool registerT() {
                const auto name = "Derive";
                // add constuct function to funcMap
                // ...
                return true;
            }
            static bool registered;
    };

    private:
        // declare funcMap

};
```

//base.h

```
#include "factory.h"

class Base : public Factory<Base> {
public:
    Base() {}
};
```

//derive.h

```
#include <string>
#include "base.h"

class Derive : public Base::Registrar<Derive> {
public:
    Derive();
};
```

//derive.cpp

```
#include "derive.h"

Derive::Derive() {}
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "base.h"

int main() {
  std::string name = "Derive";
  auto b = Base::Make(name);
  return 0;
}
```

Use `g++ -o mian ./main.cpp -Lderive.o` to get exe file.
But the function `registerT`  was not called when exec `./mian`

It works when using `g++ -o mian ./main.cpp derive.o` to get exe file. Thank you.@user17732522

The problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: It prints `name;Derive\nname2:Derive\nregistered;\nname2:Derive\nregistered;` if compiled by g++: https://godbolt.org/z/rvTMdYeea

Comment: Yes, it works when put all code together. My question is why it does not work when split the code in ```.h``` and ```.*cpp```.

Comment: Please don't remove information from the question which is necessary to understand an already-posted answer. You can instead add clarifications after the original question content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, the compilation command is wrong. The `-L` option expects a path to a directory containing libraries which are specified later. I am not sure what you are attempting by using it here, but as a result you are not linking the `derive` translation unit. `.o` files should simply be listed like source files, e.g.

```
g++ -o mian main.cpp derive.o
```

---

(This part doesn't apply anymore after the question was edited in response.)

After fixing that.

The program has undefined behavior.

This is because there is no guarantee that `Derive::name` is initialized before `Factory<Base>::Registrar<Derive>::registered`. In particular the latter is a specialization of a template and therefore has so-called *unordered dynamic initialization*, meaning that there is no ordering guarantee for it with any other global static storage duration object.

However, the initialization of the latter calls `registerT()` which accesses the former in `const auto name = T::name;`. If `name` has not been initialized at this point, accessing it causes undefined behavior.

The usual workaround is to not rely on inter-dependent dynamically-initialized static members, but instead use static functions with local static variables as you are already doing for `constructMap`. E.g. here you could use the same for `name`.

---

Additionally, even if there was no ordering issue with the static storage duration objects you defined yourself, there is still the issue that the standard streams need to be initialized before `std::cout` may be used. They are initialized through construction of an object of type `std::ios_base::Init`. Including `<iostream>` behaves as if it defined a global static storage duration object of that type, which usually guarantees it is initialized before you use it. But again, here `registered` is unordered with it.

So you must create an object of type `std::ios_base::Init` yourself in `registerT` before trying to write to `std::cout`.

Comment: I wonder why ```registerT``` is not called. Maybe it is not about the order. I know some method to get derive name by type T without using Derive::name.

Comment: @Anna How did you verify that `registerT` is not called?

Comment: I had tried ```Factory::constructMap()["Derive"] = []() -> std::shared_ptr<BaseType> {
                return std::make_shared<T>();
            };```, and printed ```std::cout << constructMap().size() << std::endl;``` in ```Make```. It outputs zero.  @user17732522

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry I made some mistakes here. The reason why I use ```-L```  is that my ```derive``` is in a static library.  ```ar r libderive1.a derive.o```  to get ```libderive1.a```. And ```g++ -o mian ./main.cpp  -Llibderive1.a```  to get exe file.  And derive instance was not made when exes ```./mian```.  I use ```g++ main.cpp  -o mian -Wl,--whole-archive -Llibderive1.a -Wl,-no--whole-archive``` to solve the problem. But it causes a lot of exception.

Comment: @Anna `-Llibderive1.a` is still wrong. `-L` expects the _directory_ in which libraries should be searched. `-l` is used to specify libraries, but without the `lib` prefix and the `.a` suffix. Also, the standard permits initialization to be deferred until the first non-initialization of a (non-inline) function or variable from the translation unit containing the initialization. That means you need to make sure that `main` odr-uses something from `derive.cpp` before calling `Make`, e.g. by directly constructing an object of type `Derive`.

Comment: Thank you. It works when I delete ```-L``` and modify -no-whole-archive to --no-whole-archive.